# Constructing a 99% confidence interval

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

From a population of trees, $n$ = 60, the sample average is 57.34 feet, and the sample variance is 4.62 feet. The question asks for a 99% confidence interval for $\mu$.

I started with 57.34 $\pm$ ...but am not sure where to go from here. I know it's 57.34 $\pm$ margin of error, but I am uncertain how to calculate margin of error. Thanks for any help, Stats geniuses.

Comment: I take it you don't know the population's standard deviation?

Comment: No, sir. Only the sample variance/SD.

Comment: In that case, you've got a $t$-distribution, right? What are the degrees of freedom?

Comment: The sample size is large enough for $\Ybar$ to approximate normal. My professor has never discussed t-distribution. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute. Is $n=60$ the population size or the sample size?

Comment: Sample size selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (approximate) interval is

$$\large{\left[\overline x-z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n} ; \ \overline x+z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}  \right]}$$

You have $\alpha=1-0.99=0.01$. Thus $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}=1-\frac{0.01}{2}=1-0.005=0.995$

Now you can use this [calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx) for a standard normal distribution and find out that $z_{0.995}=2.576$

Also given: $n=60, \overline x=57.34, s^2=4.62$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I think you meant for the sample variance to be 4.62. But besides that, thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, I´ve noticed this copy and paste flaw right now. Your are welcome.

Comment: So my final answer should just be 57.34$\pm$ .003575  ?

Comment: I have $57.34\pm 2.576\cdot \sqrt{\frac{4.62}{30}}=57.34\pm 0.175$. Here is the [calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.576*sqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B4.62%7D%7B60%7D%7D)

Comment: I multiplied 2.576 by .005. I guess that's incorrect.

Comment: Yes, that is not right. You have already used the value 0.005: $1-\frac{0.01}{2}=1-\color{blue}{0.005}=0.995$ With this value you have elavuated that $z_{0.995}=2.576$

Comment: Can I please ask you about a different question in chat? I'm sure you're busy, but I'm struggling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73541/discussion-between-callculus-and-ham-sandwich).